# using str.replace() to remove nth character from a string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that consists of strings. I would like to remove the n-th character from the end of the strings. I have the following code:

```
DF = pandas.DataFrame({'col': ['stri0ng']})
DF['col'] = DF['col'].str.replace('(.)..$','')
```

Instead of removing the third to the last character (`0` in this case), it removes `0ng`. The result should be `string` but it outputs `stri`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: is the nth character the same for every string?

Comment: No, it will be an integer though.

Comment: if you're just removing an integer you can try `df['col'].str.replace('\d+','')` @ernests answer is much better tho.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to rather replace *a single character followed by `n-1` characters at the end of the string*:

```
DF['col'] = DF['col'].str.replace('.(?=.{2}$)', '')

      col
0  string
```

If you want to make sure you're only removing digits (so that `'string'` in one special row doesn't get changed to `'strng'`), then use something like `'[0-9](?=.{2}$)'` as pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using [`pd.Series.str.slice_replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice_replace.html):

```
df['col'].str.slice_replace(4,5,'')
```

Output:

```
0    string
Name: col, dtype: object
```